# template.find() vs document.querySelector vs jquery vs template.$ performance in Meteor

Tags: performance, meteor, meteor-blaze

I know that using `template.find()` or `template.$` to search the DOM in Meteor is faster than searching all the DOM with `document.querySelector()` or jQuery. But I don't know how much faster.
I imagine it would be directly related to the number of DOM nodes of the app but I don't know if that's the case or if there's any other optimization/degradation in Meteor that makes this assumption not so proportional.
Does anyone know about a performance test/result on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`template` is not equal to `document`. A `document` can contain many `template`s. [`template.find` abstracts `$`](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/blaze/template.js#L311), but `template.find` doesn't add any functionality. So `template.$` and `template.find` will more or less perform equally. `$` is a common alias for `jQuery` and when you pass a single string to the `jQuery` function it'll go through a few more abstractions and *probably* land on `document.querySelector`. That's why [`document.querySelector` is a lot faster than `jQuery`](https://jsperf.com/queryselector-vs-jquery-2) (jsperf is down right now, so I can't tell you how much faster). `jQuery` is so much slower, that in most cases it'll probably a close call between `document.querySelector` and `template.$`.

You'll get the best performance by getting a hold of a node wrapping your target and then using native-DOM functions. If you had a wrapping element inside your template, you could use the [`template.firstNode`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_firstNode) property. Otherwise you can just do what blaze does: `template.firstNode.parentElement`. Then I'd use `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementById`. They are faster then `querySelector` because with `querySelector` the query has to be parsed first. At least most of the time it depends on the number of nodes in your wrapping node and how far inside the tree the element your searching for is.

Comment: You're right about it. I use jperf to see how big these DOM traversal differences are. From what you say I imagine that by using template.$ the query is done first and only then the result is passed to a jQuery object and not the other way around. Also, you're suggesting using native getElementByClassName (I don't use IDs in elements) not on document but on template.firstNode. But that won't search siblings I think so I have to involve my template elements in a div, for example?

Comment: `template.$` executes `$` through layers of abstractions. It's hidden [deep inside blaze](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/blaze/dombackend.js#L177). So it's slow. Searching that I found an alternative to a wrapping `div` tough. Check out my [last revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31082153/revisions). Also, to answer you question: correct.

Comment: @PauloJaneiro I found out that blaze uses `_domrange.parentNode` as a context to the `$`-selector. That means that the range of `template.$` is equivalent to `template.firstNode.parentElement`. [So I updated my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31082153/revisions)

Comment: Thanks for you investigation! I think this is very important for app quality and I wasn't doing it right and worst, I never stopped to think about it until yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say that I've noticed any real performance increase for my users, but I will say that template.find() seems to give me a performance boost in how I code.

For example

```
var someID = $('#some-id');
```

Will not be manageable until I add an array slot like so:

```
var someID = $('#some-id')[0];
```

Where as

```
var someID = template.find('#some-id')
```

Returns just that html element, meaning I don't have to treat it like an array every time.

Comment: About that Array thing.. Meteor just executes `jQuery` and returns `[0]`. [Source code](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/blaze/template.js#L311). I get that it's a little nicer, but it takes the whole chainability from jQuery. Which, as I see it, is the only nice thing about it.

Comment: I had this issue too. Then looking carefully into docs (Meteor and jQuery) I saw that this is exactly one of the advantages of using template.$(selector) specially when using classes as selector: reducing the scope of the search to the template I get JUST the element I want so it works fine AND i can apply the jQuery methods exactly the same as using jQuery. When I use jQuery sometimes I get more other elements with the same class and I get the same problem.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, yeah that's the exact problem is that I can't apply jQuery methods to it. Nice to know.