# Whats the difference between $(e.target).find and template.find('input').value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, meteor

Its probably something basic but wanted explanation of the use cases. Like sometimes hitting "enter" inputs the data, while sometimes mouseclicks work.  I'm concerned about "Gotchas" that I would have overlooked.  Like maybe it works in Firefox but not in Chrome for example.

I saw the following 2 ways, both are ways to input data into a form element.

## First way

**JavaScript**

```
var $body = $(e.target).find('[name=body]');  //defines the content
var comment = { body: $body.val() };
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-send-message" id="addcomment" data-keyboard-attach>
  <textarea id="body" name="body"></textarea>
</form>
```

## Second way

**JavaScript**

```
var message = template.find('input').value;
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="message" data-keyboard-attach>
    <input type="text" name="body" id="body">
    <button class="icon" type="submit"></button> 
</form>
```

Comment: Two different JS libraries?

Answer (score 1):

Here you can see two ways to find the value of an input/textarea with an explanation:

```
'submit .new-post': function(event){
    //returns name="postBody" content from the form you're submitting
    var postBody = event.target.postBody.value;  

    //returns the value of an html element that exists in DOM, even if its inside a different template or form.
    var postBody = $('.someClass').val()  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first code Is [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), while your second code is [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/). They both can accomplish the same thing under the right circumstances.  Also, according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31082153/2856416), meteor's `template.find` is an alias for jQuery's `$`, meaning they are the exact same.

But, the codes don't do the same thing in this case.

Your first code finds the value an element with a name of "body" inside `e.target`.  I am assuming `e` is an `Event`, but there is no way to tell with the current amount of code you gave.

The second code just gets the value of the first INPUT element it finds.